# Why is tmux opening a new terminal window?

Tags: x11, tmux, termite

When I start **tmux** in my **i3** / **termite** / **zsh** environment the default pane with the zsh prompt inside it is launched in a seperate window instead of the window in which I started tmux. Additionally I have some unicode characters at the top that can not be shown:

[image]

The statusbar of tmux remains in the window in which tmux was started.

[image]

If I close the derived window the original window outputs: `/usr/lib/xorg-server/Xorg.wrap: Only console users are allowed to run the X server`

I know from other peoples setup that tmux should run in one terminal window as I know it from and it works in the same environment with screen, so what is not working here?

Comment: It seems to be related to to termite. When I call tmux from within rxvt-unicode everything stays together within in one window. Nonetheless, I couldn't find anything similar googling that would give a hint how to solve this issue until now